# How do you run stripe listen in live mode using stripe cli and a restricted api key in an ECS container?

Tags: docker, stripe-payments, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I'm trying to run the stripe cli in an AWS ECS docker container to perform

***stripe listen***

When I do it in test mode it appears to work fine. I suspect that it's because you don't need an api-key for it to run.

I created a restricted API key and put it in secret manager, assigned a role, and I know that I can get secrets at run time because the other server container is getting the secrets without a problem at run time.

I have setup a task definition. I'll provide the json definition for the stripe container below:

```
{
            "name": "stripe-cli",
            "image": "stripe/stripe-cli",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": true,
            "command": [
                "listen",
                "--api-key",
                "${STRIPE_RESTRICTED_API_KEY}",
                "--forward-to",
                "https://redacted.com/api/stripe/webhook"
            ],
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "secrets": [
                {
                    "name": "STRIPE_RESTRICTED_API_KEY",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:accountId:secret:secret_store_redacted:secret_name_redacted::"
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "redacted",
                    "condition": "HEALTHY"
                }
            ],
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": true,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {},
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "healthCheck": {
                "command": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "stripe version || exit 1"
                ],
                "interval": 30,
                "timeout": 5,
                "retries": 3,
                "startPeriod": 0
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error when I try to deploy the stripe cli with live mode on

"message": "For security reasons, the Stripe CLI only permits the use of restricted keys when in live mode. To generate restricted keys for use in live mode, use the `stripe login` command."

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to access the restricted API key secret from secret manager into commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't need to run a stripe cli container for my project. I was trying to listen to stripe events but it turns out that this is only needed locally. So I removed the cli from the deployment and my project is listening to events just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is there might be some live and test mode mixes here. If you're trying to forward live mode events, you'd want to follow these steps:

1/ Create live mode restricted key in Dashboard with Stripe CLI permissions enabled

2/ Use stripe `login --interactive` to input restricted key created in Step 1

3/ Listen and forward the event

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can I do something like 

stripe login --interactive --api-key $RESTRICTED_API_KEY

I'm trying to do this autonomously in the command

Answer (score 0):

```
"command": [
                "listen",
                "--api-key",
                "${STRIPE_RESTRICTED_API_KEY}",
                "--forward-to",
                "https://redacted.com/api/stripe/webhook"
            ]
```

When you pass the arguments this way, they don't undergo shell expansion. The literal string `${STRIPE_RESTRICTED_API_KEY}` gets passed to your executable, which is of course not a valid key.

I'm not familiar with Stripe CLI, but brief googling shows [this](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/api_keys):

> You can set two environment variables, which take precedence over all other values:
>
> `STRIPE_API_KEY`: the API key to use for the CLI.

If it works as advertised indeed, you just need to name your environment variable `STRIPE_API_KEY` and omit the `--api-key` argument.

For the shell expansion to work, you'll need to invoke an actual shell:

```
"command": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "stripe listen --api-key \"$STRIPE_RESTRICTED_API_KEY\" --forward-to https://redacted.com/api/stripe/webhook"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried this as well, and though I am seeing that the environment variable is coming through, I'm still getting the same error. I even tested giving the restricted key full access to see if that was the issue. It's as if it's not even taking the key at all.

Comment: @Chris: if you can see the variable coming through, it looks like it's a Stripe cli problem vs ECS problem. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Stripe and can't help you with that

Comment: thanks for your help, the shell part that you shared did help me get a bit further though.